# Room doesn't recognize some class parameters when creating select queries

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, getter

If I have a class/entity:

```
@Entity
class Person(yearOfBirth: Int) {
  val ageInYears: Int
    get() = currentYear - yearOfBirth
}
```

And want to create a Dao:

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE ageInYears >= 21")
  fun getAdults(): List<Person>
}
```

I get an problem in the IDE that says "Cannot resolve symbol 'ageInYears'".  It seems Room can't deal with parameters with getters.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: `@DatabaseView` may help you. Check out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views#create

Answer (score 0):

Without `@ColumnInfo(name = "ageInYears")` annotation, this might be mapped as `age_in_years`.
That `@Entity` annotation also lacks an argument; eg. `@Entity(tableName = "persons")`.
When not providing annotations, it's always the class or member names in kebab case.

When editing the `@Dao`, code auto-complete also knows the column names.
And it's rather this part of the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: Adding a column annotation yields the IDE problem "This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'".  The column does not show up in the auto complete in either case.